# Add css class on click in Angular 6

Tags: angular, css, typescript, css-transitions, angular6

I want add animation class continuously on clicking for that I have written below  code

[My Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fqthri)

My problem is when I click first time then only first time animation works on second click animation not working. Please help.

Comment: Can you check out this one :https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lky158

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add `setTimeout` for delay to add `add` class

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/add-css-class-on-click-in-angular-6?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

```
rotate(event){
    event.srcElement.classList.remove("rotate");
    setTimeout(()=>{
      event.srcElement.classList.add("rotate");
    },0)
  }
```

Comment: This is brilliant! With this you do not need to create any state-tracking variables ❤